# OS X File number

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

I just noticed in File Viewer (random all-files reader) on OS X, that all files have a Misc. attribute called "File Number". It contains values like 17022656, 17022354 and 435457.

I tried to look online for it's meaning, but as it's such a global meaning I couldn't find much of worth.

Does anyone know what this means? Some sort of index in which order files were originally created on the HFS+ partition?

[image]

Just curious :)

Answer (score 0):

Im unsure, but this is probaby the [inode number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) for the file. It's the unique identifier for a metadata structure for the file on a volume.